# Internal Server Error 500 when calling a REST service in VB

Tags: json, vb.net, rest, api, web-services

I'm working with a coworker's code trying to recreate his REST web service in a console application.  I'm very new to web services and VB so it's been quite difficult for me.  It will work fine on his but I keep getting an Internal Server Error (500).  I have looked this up and some suggestions I found were changing "POST" to "GET" but I received "Cannot get content body with this verb-type".  I've seen forums about something like this not working from another person's machine.  My coworker and I have tried going through it over and over but getting the same results.

This is the Console App

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Xml

Module RestConsoleClient
Private req As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
Private res As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Private responseText As String = ""

Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim url As String = ""

    Try
        If args.Count < 1 OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(args(0)) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Endpoint Address is required as commandline argument;" _
                              & vbCrLf & "Copy/Paste one of the endpoint addresses from My.Settings into the Debug commandline arguments section" _
                              & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press ENTER to start over...")
            Console.ReadKey()
            Return
        Else
            url = args(0)
        End If

        req = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        req.Method = "POST"

        '** The conditions below allowed for generic raw data to be input as text vs. processing input data as a json object.
        '** These conditions became redundant with the addition of config for WebContentTypeMapper and corresponding class to accept
        '**     a post declared with application/json ContentType as generic raw data, and then SUBSEQUENTLY de/serialize the json data as necessary
        'If url.Contains("streamweaver") Then
        '    req.ContentType = "text"
        'ElseIf url.Contains("auth") Then
        '    req.ContentType = "application/json"   '; charset=utf-8"
        'Else
        '    'No other options are yet determined
        'End If
        req.Timeout = 30000

        Dim sJson As String = "{""Name"":""Ashu"",""Age"":""29"",""Exp"":""7 Years"",""Technology"":"".NET""}"
        Dim postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sJson)
        req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length
        Dim requestStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)

        res = CType(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        ' I retained the basics for response reception even though it was not integral to this test
        Dim responseStream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
        Dim streamReader = New StreamReader(responseStream)

        responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

        Console.WriteLine("HTTP Response: " & res.StatusCode & " - " & res.StatusDescription.Trim)
        Console.WriteLine("[ Response Data: " & responseText.Trim & " ]")
        Console.ReadKey()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Try

End Sub
End Module
```

This here is the Interface

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web

<ServiceContract> _
Public Interface IRestServiceImpl

'<OperationContract> _
'<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="xml/{id}")> _
'Function XMLData(id As String) As String

'<OperationContract> _
'<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="json/{id}")> _
'Function JSONData(id As String) As String

<OperationContract> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate:="auth")> _
Function Auth(rData As Stream) As ResponseData

<OperationContract> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate:="streamweaver")> _
Function StreamWeaver(sData As Stream) As String

End Interface
```

And here is the class

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class RestServiceImpl
Implements IRestServiceImpl

Private filePathOnServer As String = My.Settings.OutputFolder

'Public Function XMLData(id As String) As String Implements IRestServiceImpl.XMLData
'    Return "You requested product " & id
'End Function

'Public Function JSONData(id As String) As String Implements IRestServiceImpl.JSONData
'    Return "You requested product " & id
'End Function

Public Function Auth(request As Stream) As ResponseData Implements IRestServiceImpl.Auth

    Dim streamReader = New StreamReader(request)
    Dim requestText As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

    Dim rData As RequestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RequestData)(requestText)

    Dim response = New ResponseData() With { _
        .Name = rData.Name, _
        .Age = rData.Age, _
        .Exp = rData.Exp, _
        .Technology = rData.Technology _
    }

    Dim fileOutput As String = "As of " & DateTime.Now & ", " _
                               & response.Name.Trim & " is a person who is " _
                               & response.Age.Trim & " years old, having " _
                               & response.Exp.Trim & " of experience with " _
                               & response.Technology.Trim & " technology."
    Console.SetError(New StreamWriter("C:\Users\apearson\Documents\Eureka.txt"))
    Console.[Error].WriteLine(fileOutput)
    Console.[Error].Close()

    Dim ctx As WebOperationContext = WebOperationContext.Current
    If rData IsNot Nothing Then
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted
    Else
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable
    End If

    Return response
End Function

Public Function StreamWeaver(reqData As Stream) As String Implements IRestServiceImpl.StreamWeaver
    StreamWeaver = Nothing

    Dim ctx As WebOperationContext = WebOperationContext.Current
    If reqData IsNot Nothing Then
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted
    Else
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable
    End If

    Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(reqData)
    StreamWeaver = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

    Console.SetError(New StreamWriter(filePathOnServer.Trim & "\RestServiceJSONRaw.txt"))
    Console.[Error].WriteLine(DateTime.Now & ": " & vbCrLf & StreamWeaver.Trim)
    Console.[Error].Close()

    Return StreamWeaver

End Function

End Class
```

If there is anymore information needed, let me know.  Again, this is kind of new to me.

Comment: a HTTP 500 error indicates something went wrong on the server side (i.e the REST service in this case). So you'd better debug that or check its logs. P.S. Changing the method from POST to GET (or anything else) is unlikely to work - usually a webservice method is designed to respond to a specific HTTP method (or "verb" as they're sometimes known), and also, as your error pointed out, GET requests don't send a content body.

Comment: I don't know how to check logs.  How do I do that exactly?

Comment: Windows Event Viewer (on the machine where the REST service is running) normally shows exception or warning details. Alternatively you can run the service in debug mode and, as you can see from the code, it will log things to the console.